# Get Header Value (Set-Cookie) out of Response from a ServiceReference Call

Tags: c#, .net, soap

I'm working on a project where I have to call an API in SOAP web service form and get a response back. When the response comes back, there is a Set-Cookie value I have to pull from the header and pass along in the header Cookie value with subsequent API requests. Initially, I've been building my SOAP document from scratch using `XmlWriter`. A teammate of mine turned me on to using a Service Reference which meant that I didn't have to write any of the custom XML (BIG WIN).

My main problem is that I have to get the header value, without that, the API calls won't work. Is there a way to get the response header while still being able to use a Service Reference and all the goodness that comes with it?

Comment: That's a pretty dumb API. SOAP headers should be used instead of cookies. SOAP headers could be used regardless of the underlying transport protocol, but cookies will only work with HTTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent most of the day trying to figure this one out... I ended up writing a WCF service to simulate setting a cookie and sending it out as part of an OperationContract (although this is bad practice, something I wouldn't do practically as WCF isn't HTTP only).

Initially I thought Message Inspectors would do the trick, however after a few hours of code-iteration I ended up writing a custom WebClient class to "simulate" the service reference, which allowed me to see the Headers in a CookieContainer.

So after trying all these different ideas and writing pages and pages of code, as per most times I try something I haven't done before, I stumbled across an article in google (whilst searching for something completely different to the original problem):

http://megakemp.com/2009/02/06/managing-shared-cookies-in-wcf/

Read the section (**Ad-hoc cookie management**), here's my implementation (using the test Service I created to simulate your problem). You could probably do more sanity/error checking on the section where I re-assemble the cookies from the header string...

```
        List<string> strings = null;

        // Using Custom Bindings to allow Fiddler to see the HTTP interchange.
        BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();            
        binding.AllowCookies = true;
        binding.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
        binding.ProxyAddress = new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:8888");
        binding.UseDefaultWebProxy = false;

        EndpointAddress url = new EndpointAddress("http://192.168.20.4:42312/Classes/TestService.svc");

        using (TestServiceClient client = new TestServiceClient(binding,url))
        {                
            using (new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
            {
                strings = new List<string>(client.WSResult());
                HttpResponseMessageProperty response = (HttpResponseMessageProperty)OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties[HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name];

                CookieCollection cookies = new CookieCollection();
                foreach (string str in response.Headers["Set-Cookie"].ToString().Split(";".ToCharArray()))
                {
                    Cookie cookie = new Cookie(str.Split("=".ToCharArray())[0].Trim(), str.Split("=".ToCharArray())[1].Trim());
                    cookies.Add(cookie);
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: I didn't use all of this, and actually found [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.wshttpbinding.allowcookies%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that used a similar approach. I didn't need a `CookieCollection`. I just grabbed the `response` the same way you did above, but then was able to use `response.Headers["Set-Cookie"]` to grab the value.

Answer (score 1):

So I spent some more time digging, searching, messing around with `MessageBehavior`s and web.config settings, and finally found something that solved what I needed. I marked the answer above as the answer to this question because it's close enough to how i solved my issue, but I think the way I've done it is a bit cleaner and is different enough from the above answer to warrant more than a comment.

From [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.wshttpbinding.allowcookies%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you can use the `OperationContextScope` to inspect the response and add values to the subsequent request.

My code ended up looking like this:

```
string sharedCookie = string.Empty;

using (MyClient client = new MyClient())
{
    client.RequestThatContainsCookieValue();

    // This gets the response context
    HttpResponseMessageProperty response = (HttpResponseMessageProperty)OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties[HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name];

    sharedCookie = response.Headers["Set-Cookie"];

    // Create a new request property
    HttpRequestMessageProperty request = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();

    // And add the cookie to the Header
    request.Headers["Cookie"] = sharedCookie;

    // Add the new request properties to the outgoing message
    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = request;

    var response = client.ThisCallPassesTheCookieInTheHeader();
}
```

Comment: Glad you managed to get what you needed! I didn't realise you wanted to send the cookie back as part of your request. The reason I created the cookie-container is because using that implementation I can pass the container from the webservice call to a HTTP POST call using a REST API or some other non-WCF/non-SOAP service, so I'm not trapped only using the ServiceReference framework there. Thanks for the voteup/answer though!